# Need to retrieve single cell in sql db with pdo

Tags: php, mysql

I want to put the value of `count` into a variable and display it on the page.

here's my code:

```
<?php 

try {
$pdo = new PDO('Database info');
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    exit('Database error.');
}



        $query = $pdo->prepare("select count from counter where count_id=1");
        $query->execute();

        return $query;

        echo $query;

?>
```

This isn't working... any suggestions on how i should change this to get the count to display in a variable?

Thanks.

Comment: Rewrite the query like this `select count(*) from counter`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change to:

```
    $query = $pdo->prepare("select count(*) from counter where count_id=1");
    $query->execute();
    $count = $query->fetchColumn();
    echo $count;
```

Comment: this doesn't work... is there something wrong with how I am putting the result of the query into a variable? I'm not sure

Answer (score 0):

Modify the query as follows

```
$count = $con->query("SELECT COUNT(*) as num from counter where count_id=1")
         ->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

echo  $count['num'];
```

Comment: this does not work, it just gives me a blank result. I know the database info is correct and the rows exists... it just gives me a blank page... with no errors

Comment: I have modified the query.